# static full page slider with two divs(one top, one bottom)

Tags: css, slider

I have one static full page slider with the css :

```
#slider {
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0!important;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index:-1;
}
```

and a header at the top of page with the following css :

```
header {
height:137px;
text-align:center;
margin:10px;
}
```

and a footer at the bottom of page with the following css :

```
footer {
height:34px;
margin:10px;
background:rgba(39,39,39,1);
min-width:1000px;
}
```

Is there any way to keep header at the top and footer at the bottom of every page (responsive page)? The height main-content is set at min-height:700px to keep footer at bottom.

Comment: just set both the header and footer `position:fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah simple. [**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/38gfzbvz/)

```
.header {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height:137px;
text-align:center;
margin:10px;
margin-top: 0;
min-width: 1000px;
}

.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height:34px;
margin:10px;
background:rgba(39,39,39,1);
min-width:1000px;
}
```